# Sql logic insert from table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

My situation is that i have 2 tables in my db. The one is with alerts, the other is with devices. Alerts table has hostname, message, location, time_logged. In the alerts table I keep logs for all events happened. So the thing is that I want to take the alerts.message and for each log to update it in the devices.status (status will keep the message). So i have this sql for now:

```
       $sql = 'SELECT alerter_db.alerts.hostname, message,time_logged, devices.hostname,status FROM
       alerts,devices WHERE alerts.hostname = devices.hostname ORDER BY time_logged ASC';
```

and i have a

```
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die('error')){
        $my_sql = "INSERT INTO alerter_db.devices (status) VALUE ('".$row['message']."') WHERE    
        devices.hostname = alerts.hostname";
        mysql_query($my_sql);
```

But unfortunately I am little confused about the logic. So can anybody help me solve this problem ?

Comment: may be some usefull http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I ended with this code but still not working

        UPDATE devices 
        JOIN alerts 
        ON devices.hostname = alerts.hostname 
        SET devices.`status` = alerts.message

Comment: can you show your table structure and exception message?